# Почему не выводится динамический массив? В чем ошибка?

Tags: c, функции, указатели, динамические-массивы, объявление

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
FILE *f_out, *f_in;
double *a;
int n,m,i,j;

void output_0(double A[n][m]){
    for (i=1; i <= n; i++){
        for (j=1; j <= m; j++){
            printf("a[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
            A[i][j] = (float)1/(i+j);
            printf ("%f\n", A[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void output_1(double A[n][m]){
    int i,j;
    f_out = fopen("out.txt", "w");
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        for (j=0; j<m; j++){
            A[i][j] = (float)1/(i+j);
            printf("A[%d][%d] = %f", i, j, A[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

int main (int argc, int** argv){
    int in, out, next, n, m;
    system("chcp 1251");

    do{
        printf("input from console - 0 or from file - 1? ");
        scanf ("%d", &in);
        printf("output from console - 0 or from file - 1? ");
        scanf("%d", &out);

        if (in ==0){
                printf("Введите количество строк: ");
                scanf("%d", &n);
                printf("Введите количество столбцов: ");
                scanf("%d", &m);
        } else if (in == 1){
                f_in = fopen("in.txt", "r");
                fscanf(f_in, "%d, %d", &n, &m);
        } else {
                printf("ОШИБКА!");
        }

        a = (double*)malloc(n*m*sizeof(double));

        if (out == 0){
                output_0(a);
        } else if (out == 1){
                output_1(a);
        } else {
                printf("ОШИБКА!");
        }
        free(a);
        printf("\n\nNEXT - 1, EXIT - 0? ");
        scanf("%d", &next);

    } while (next !=0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код по крайней мере не корректный в этом фрагменте

```
int n,m,i,j;

void output_0(double A[n][m]){
```

Глобальные переменные `n` и `m`, как переменные со статической продолжительностью жизни, инициализируются 0. То есть объявление функции в действительности выглядит как

```
void output_0(double A[0][0]){
```

то есть функция использует в качестве параметра указатель на массив переменной длины с размерностью, равной 0. Аналогичная проблема имеет место для функции

```
void output_1(double A[n][m]){
```

Эти глобальные переменные `n` и `m` не имеют ничего общего с локальными переменными `n` и `m`, объявленными в `main`

```
int main (int argc, int** argv){
    int in, out, next, n, m;
```

К тому же имейте в виду, что индексация массивов начинается с 0. Поэтому циклы, подобные этим, взятые из определения одной из функций

```
for (i=1; i <= n; i++){
    for (j=1; j <= m; j++){
        printf("a[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
        A[i][j] = (float)1/(i+j);
```

также не корректные.

И в этом предложении вы не выделяете  в памяти двумерный массив

```
a = (double*)malloc(n*m*sizeof(double));
```

Поэтому такое обращение к массиву `A[i][j]` будет не верным.

Так что программа не имеет смысла.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение. А как мне правильно передать динамический массив в функцию, да так, чтобы значения n, m сохранились?

Comment: @АлияГафурова Вам следует объявить функции по крайней мере следующим образом void output_0( int n, int m, double A[n][m]); и передавать в первых двух аргументов размеры массива

Comment: Наконец что-то появилось, но всего один элемент (внизу скрин)

Comment: нет, все получилось, нашла мелкую ошибку. Спасибо Вам большое, столько мучалась, а оказалось не так сложно!